# Setter of BindableProperty of Integer never called from xaml (Xamarin.forms)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms.

I set BindableProperty of integer. 
But it's setter never called and not even set from xaml.

```
<... SelectedIndex="{Binding myValue}">
```

Is there anything I did wrong?

Thanks.

```
   public class CircleSegmentControl : StackLayout
        {
            public static readonly BindableProperty SegmentInitialIndexProperty = BindableProperty.Create("SelectedIndex", typeof(int), typeof(CircleSegmentControl), 0);
            public int SelectedIndex {
set{ 
Debug.WriteLine("setter"); 
SetValue(SegmentInitialIndexProperty, value); 
SelectIndex(value); 
}
get{
Debug.WriteLine("getter"); 
return (int)GetValue(SegmentInitialIndexProperty);
}
}
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Not sure about Xamarin, but probably the same problem as with WPF dependency properties: you must not call anything else than `GetValue` and `SetValue` in the `get` and `set` methods of the property wrapper. To get notified about property value changes (to call your `SelectIndex` method), you should register a `propertyChanged` delegate with another overload of `BindableProperty.Create`.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks. Your answer is correct! it's called in propertyChanged delegate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the same applies as for WPF dependency properties. You must not call anything else than `GetValue` and `SetValue` in the `get` and `set` methods of the property wrapper:

```
public int SelectedIndex
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedIndexProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedIndexProperty, value); }
}
```

To get notified about property value changes (to call your `SelectIndex` method), you should register a `propertyChanged` delegate with another overload of [`BindableProperty.Create`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty/).

Comment: Thanks Clements. Your answer is right. I had faced another issue. This ValueChanged delegate should be static because Bindable Property is static. So I can't access class instance.. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry. I figured it out. Delegate has a 'bindable object' as a parameter which is Instance.