# Xamarin.Forms: Bindable Property in CustomView not hit

Tags: xamarin.forms, bindableproperty

I define a CustomView with one Bindable Property. To make things clearer, I removed all code unnessesary to understand my problem.
This is my XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Packer.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="vm:ContainerItemViewModel"
             x:Class="Packer.CustomViews.ContainerView">
    <ContentView.BindingContext>
        <vm:ContainerItemViewModel/>
    </ContentView.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Text="Hello World!" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

...and this is my code behind:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Packer.CustomViews
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ContainerView : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemIdProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemId), typeof(int), typeof(ContainerView), -1);
 
        public ContainerView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public int ItemId
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(ItemIdProperty);
            set
            {
                SetValue(ItemIdProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With `xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:Packer.CustomViews`" This CustomView is called as follows:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
     <custom:ContainerView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemId="{Binding ItemId}" />
     <Label Text="{Binding ItemId}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Debugging this app as UWP, I can't see property ItemId being hit. However, the label following the Custom View is displayed properly, as well as the "Hello World" Label defined in the Custom View.

This is my configuration:

[image]

Comment: May I ask what's the BindingContext for the page which consumes the ContainerView?

Comment: `ContainerView` seems to be fine, I have a feeling this has to do with your Page's binding context or the binding itself

Comment: Hi,  I made some updates to explain my answer. Please consider accepting the answer if you think it is helpful! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updates:**

When you set this in xaml:

```
<ContentView.BindingContext>
    <vm:ContainerItemViewModel/>
</ContentView.BindingContext>
```

It just like you set this in page:

```
<custom:ContainerView BindingContext=ContainerViewModel HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemId="{Binding ItemId}" />
```

Of course we could not get the ItemId property change because we maually set the BindingContext to ContainerViewModel (We know that ItemId is not in it).

But when I set

```
Content.BindingContext = new ContainerItemViewModel();
```

It means we just set the BindingContext for the ContainerView's Content. We could also receive the changes of ItemId.

---

If you want to [Detect property changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#detect-property-changes) for BindableProperty, you could use a **callback** method instead of adding some logic in Setter.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemIdProperty =
           BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemId), typeof(int), typeof(ContainerView), -1,propertyChanged:OnItemIdPropertyChanged);

private static void OnItemIdPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var a = (int)newValue;
}
```

I don't know why you use a **ContainerItemViewModel** for  ContainerView. Because the BindingContext can inherit from the parent page. If you still want to do so, you could delete:

```
<!--<ContentView.BindingContext>
    <vm:ContainerItemViewModel/>
</ContentView.BindingContext>-->
```

And set it in code-behind like this:

```
public ContainerView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Notice here, please set Content.BindingContext here
    Content.BindingContext = new ContainerItemViewModel();
}
```

Now if you set a breakpoint in OnItemIdPropertyChanged method, and it will hit the code. If you still have any question, feel free to ask.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Liqun Shen-MSFT's answer solves my problem.

However, the breakpoint in the ItemId setter is not hit but event OnItemIdChanged:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ItemIdProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemId), typeof(int), typeof(ContainerView), propertyChanged:OnItemIdChanged);

private static void OnItemIdChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
}
```

This is a strange behaviour that I did not expect.

Comment: In my answer, you could see I have set ```Content.BindingContext = new ContainerItemViewModel();```, this helps set the BindingContext for the ContainerView. I don't understand why you just comment this line.

Comment: Hi, I think I haven't explained my answer clearly. So I add some explanations to my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Ok, you are right. Because of a typo your suggestion seemed not to work for me at first. See my edits above.

Comment: I think this behaviour is by design. You could see some threads also talk about this: [Setter of bindable property never fires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319127/setter-of-bindable-property-never-fires), [Setter of BindableProperty of Integer never called from xaml (Xamarin.forms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104455/setter-of-bindableproperty-of-integer-never-called-from-xaml-xamarin-forms)

Comment: This worked, however, for all content pages I defined before. So I was confused.

Comment: Okay, what makes you confused? The BindingContext or the Setter method for the BindableProperty?

Comment: ...that in all my previous cases, the ItemId setter was hit but not in case of a custom view.

Comment: Then I think that's not a BindableProperty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255237/discussion-between-bernd-morgeneyer-and-liqun-shen-msft).